# Getting inputs from a checkbox table form

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm writing a flask application and want to pull a user's availability from a table of checkboxes corresponding to the 30-minute slot selected as shown in the snippet of code below.

```
<form method="POST" action="_avail" style="margin: 5% 5% auto 5%; overflow:auto">
    <div class="signup column">
        <table id="am">
        <tr style="background-color:transparent">
            <th style="background-color:transparent;border:none">AM</th>
            <th>Mo</th> <th>Tu</th> <th>We</th> <th>Th</th> <th>Fr</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>08:00</th>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="mo" value="8"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tu" value="8"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="we" value="8"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="th" value="8"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="fr" value="8"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>:30</th>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="mo" value="8:30"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="tu" value="8:30"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="we" value="8:30"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="th" value="8:30"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="fr" value="8:30"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

However, when the back-end attempts to fetch the data from the table, only the first selected slot for each day of the week is returned. From my knowledge of forms, I thought by just calling the request for the specific name would return all value checked for that name. Is there some convention with HTML tables that I'm overlooking?

```
mon_avail = request.form.get('mo', '', type=str)
tue_avail = request.form.get('tu', '', type=str)
wed_avail = request.form.get('we', '', type=str)
thu_avail = request.form.get('th', '', type=str)
fri_avail = request.form.get('fr', '', type=str)
```

Comment: Could you try instead of `.get`, use `.getlist` like `mon_avail = request.form.getlist('mo', '', type=str)`

Comment: Thanks! That was it.